# htaccess dynamic .json rewrite to php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite dynamic .json files from json to php (requesting file.json comes from file.php) This doesn't seem to work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.json$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "[doesn't seem to work](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/133817)"? What is the behavior you observe, and how does it differ from the behavior you expect?

Comment: Also add along with what is asked in first comment(which is a required information very much), please do let us know if your .htaccess file and your php files(where you want to rewrite) are present in same folder or not too, thank you.

Comment: They are in the same directory.  And "It doesn't  s̶e̶e̶m̶ t̶o̶ work" as written.  Thanks!

Comment: _Aside:_ The filesystem check that the requested `.json` URL does not map to a directory is most certainly redundant (do you have filesystem directories that end in `.json`?!). And unless you do have physical `.json` files in this area of the filesystem then the "file" check is also superfluous. Filesystem checks are relatively expensive, so are best avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It was the rewrite base; commented it out & it worked!
Thanks all!

Comment: That would imply your `.htaccess` file is in a subdirectory, not in the document root? Unless otherwise stated, it is generally assumed that the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root directory.